# vectorial ODE in mathematica

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, maxima

I want to solve the following equation in mathematica :

```
DSolve[{X'[t] == A.X[t], X[0] == ( {{0},{0}} )}, X[t], t]
```

It is a system of 2 ODEs coupled by the matrix `A`, that I don't want to put in the form `{{a,b},{c,d}}` in order to have the output as a function of matrix exponential.

Mathematica understands that but gives a solution strangely expresed as :

```
 {{X[t] -> 
     InverseFunction[Dot, 2, 2][A, 
         E^(t A.1)
         InverseFunction[InverseFunction[Dot, 2, 2], 2, 2][A, 0]]}}
```

Where it indeed uses a matrix exponential, but also relies on a strange notation InverseFunction [...]

My question is how to get rid of this InverseFunction notation to have a more readable expression. Do I for example have a manner to postulate that `A` is a `(2,2)` matrix, invertible, with inverse `B`?

If I can hope a better result with maxima, please advise.
Thanks a lot for help

Comment: Thanks Nasser. Tried with lower case letters but still having the same strange expression for the solution : {{x[t] -> 
   InverseFunction[Dot, 2, 2][a, 
    E^(t a.1)
      InverseFunction[InverseFunction[Dot, 2, 2], 2, 2][a, 0]]}}